# Build a package for Debian

Tags: debian, package-management

I'm try to build a Debian package, using this commands :

```
debian/rules clean
dpkg-source -b .
debian/rules build
debian/rules binary
```

I've got this file :

```
myprog_1.1.0.orig.tar.gz
myprog_1.1.0-1.dsc
myprog_1.1.0-1.debian.tar.xz
myprog_1.1.0-1_all.deb
myprog-doc_1.1.0-1_all.deb
```

All the steps have been completed with success. When I open the directory `myprog-1.1.0/debian`, I find something, which looks like to a Debian package. But my libraries are not in there, they are under `myprog-1.1.0/debian/tmp/usr/lib/...`.

And the compiled libraires are not in my `.deb`.

- Is this normal?
- Is there something else to do to finish this package ?
- If I'd want it to distribute it, should I recreate a `tar.gz` from `myprog-1.1.0`?

Comment: Did you look into the `.deb` file? If the files are not in there, is your `.dsc` correct and referring to the libraries that need to be included in your `.deb`?

Comment: Into the .deb file, there are the same files that in "myprog-1.1.0/debian/myprog", which contains /DEBIAN and /usr/share/some_doc ... But not /usr/lib.

My .dsc seems good.

Comment: Is this your own packaging, or someone elses? Regardless use `debuild -uc -us`. `debuild` is from the `devscripts` package. What you you using to look inside the debian binary package?

Comment: It's my own packaging. I use Xarchiver to look inside

Comment: It has been a while since I created my own `.deb` files, but I think you are missing something in your `.dsc` if things get compiled but not included in the `.deb`.

Comment: When you say some things are missing in my .dsc, I'm angry with you, but, isn't it a file automatically generated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the important thing your build is missing is that on `make install` the `Makefile` honours the `DESTDIR` variable (which on packaging target should be something like `./debian/myprog`).

After the build, before the packaging, the library should be in `myprog-1.1.0/debian/myprog/usr/lib` not `tmp`.

Just as reference: Following is a minimal working example and the commands I've used to get the package. Put all these files in the directory `myprog-1.0.1`.

---

`Makefile`:

```
CFLAGS += -O2 -Wall
LIBS += -L$(BUILDDIR)/usr/lib -lfunc

ifeq ($(BUILDDIR),)
BUILDDIR = build
endif

all: $(BUILDDIR)/usr/bin/myprog $(BUILDDIR)/usr/lib/libfunc.so

install: $(BUILDDIR)/usr/bin/myprog $(BUILDDIR)/usr/lib/libfunc.so
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib
    cp $(BUILDDIR)/usr/bin/myprog $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin
    cp $(BUILDDIR)/usr/lib/libfunc.so $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib

dir-stamp:
    mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)/usr/bin $(BUILDDIR)/usr/lib
    touch $@

$(BUILDDIR)/usr/bin/myprog: myprog.c $(BUILDDIR)/usr/lib/libfunc.so
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

$(BUILDDIR)/usr/lib/libfunc.so: func.c dir-stamp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $<

clean:
    -rm -fr dir-stamp $(BUILDDIR)
```

`myprog.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "func.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("%d\n", func(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2])));
    return 0;
}
```

`func.h`:

```
#ifndef FUNC_H
#define FUNC_H
int func(int a, int b);
#endif
```

`func.c`:

```
#include "func.h"
int func(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

And here the commands:

```
dh_make --createorig
#choose type of package (single)
rm debian/*.ex debian/*.EX (if not needed)
# update: depcheck against the built command
dpkg-depcheck -d ./build/usr/bin/myprog 1 1
#edit debian/control (add Build-Depends)
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot
dpkg --contents ../myprog_1.0.1-1_i386.deb

./
./usr/
./usr/share/
./usr/share/doc/
./usr/share/doc/myprog/
./usr/share/doc/myprog/changelog.Debian.gz
./usr/share/doc/myprog/copyright
./usr/share/doc/myprog/README.Debian
./usr/lib/
./usr/lib/libfunc.so
./usr/bin/
./usr/bin/myprog
```

---

Using `cmake`:

I'm not confident with `cmake`, but a quick test worked.

The only odd thing is the prefix at command line to generate the `Makefile`, could be a problem depending on the complexity of your project.

By default `cmake` uses `/usr/local` as prefix the an error is given building the package on `rmdir`, but using `/usr` works.

Notice also I've added `OWNER_WRITE`, because there was an error removing `myprog` rpath, there's probably a better way to set the wanted permissions correctly.

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(myprog C)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-O2 -Wall)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(myprog myprog.c)
ADD_LIBRARY(func SHARED func.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myprog func)
INSTALL(TARGETS myprog DESTINATION "bin"
        PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE)
INSTALL(TARGETS func DESTINATION "lib"
        PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE GROUP_READ WORLD_READ)
```

Generate the `Makefile` using:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr .
```

Comment: Indeed I don't use DESTDIR, but how can I use the variable, knowing that my Makefile is generated by CMake ? Thank's for your answer!

Comment: I'm not really confident with `CMake` but seem to be [supported](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Does_CMake.27s_.22make_install.22_support_DESTDIR.3F), try `make install DESTDIR=/somedir` and see if it work as expected, then make sure `debian/rules` use an absolute path as cmake require

Comment: @cooow see the update using cmake

Comment: Thank's for you help, your instructions help me.
Finally, I've used override_dh_auto_install: dh_auto_install --destdir=debian/myprog , into debian/rules, but your method seems good too.