# How do I install Apache as a "service unit"?

Tags: debian, systemd, apache-httpd

I wanted to run Apache as a service so it will start on bootup, so I tried:

`sudo systemctl start apache2.service`

but got the error:

> Failed to start apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not found.

So, apparently I need to install apache as a "service unit". The Apache documentation does not appear to have information on how to do this, just the old confusing init.d instructions which do not work anymore.

Comment: Did you actually install `apache2`?

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes, works fine. I usually start it with apachectl but I would like to start it as a service now (or some kind of startup script) so that it starts automatically on boot.

Comment: What Debian is that?

Comment: What do you get from `systemctl list-unit-files | grep apache`? Also, did you install it via `apt` or did you compile it from source?

Comment: @NasirRiley I get nothing when I enter that. I built it from source, but added many features. Possibly I missed the one that automatically enables it to run as a service?

Answer (score 2):

Building `apache2` from source does not create a service for it. That is why you are getting the error that the service isn't found.

You will either need to create one manually or install `apache2` via `apt`. The latter is much easier and you can also install all of the features that you added. To get it to run at boot, you will need to use `systemctl enable apache2` after creating the service or installing apache2 via `apt`.

Comment: Ok, so how do I manually create a service unit for Apache? That is the question?

Comment: You could [just copy the apache2.service file from the Debian source](https://sources.debian.org/src/apache2/2.4.25-3+deb9u6/debian/apache2.service/), replace the paths to represent your source install, and place it in `/etc/systemd/system/`.  After `systemctl daemon-reload` it should be available

Comment: @NasirRiley That's what `systemctl enable apache2.service` does (assuming the `[Install]` section has been correctly configured.) I'd recommend enabling it through `systemctl enable` rather than creating symbolic links by hand.

Comment: Building it from the _Debian_ source _does_ include the service units, as well as a number of patches that make Apache use Debian paths and whatnot.  The problem here is likely to be building from the wrong source.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger You are correct. It even says so when you run `systemctl enable service`. I'll remove that comment since it's uneccessary redundant.

Comment: @JdeBP In this case, it does not create the service units. Even if it were built from Debian source, it would need to done as root to create the units in the correct location and load the daemon as a normal user wouldn't have write access to that location.

Comment: You have an incorrect notion of what building from a source package does.  Building from the Debian source package will yield executables, service units, data files, doco, and maintainer scripts, all in the appropriate binary packages ready to be installed.  It will include all of the Debian patches and additions (such as the very service unit files in question) that building from the wrong source does not.

Comment: @JdeBP I just said that. The issue is that it would need to be done as root. If the user is running as root then it would make more sense to just use `apt` anyway. Whether or not the source is wrong depends on what the user is trying to do.

Comment: No, you said some incorrect things about it not creating the service units, when it does, and the build process needing to be run as the super user, when it does not.  And you've just repeated them.  You have an incorrect notion of building from a source package.  We already have Q&As from people doing this that demonstrate the right ideas, such as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304590/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143781/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468218/5132 just for starters.  I suggest reading and learning.

Comment: @JdeBP I said that compiling apache from source doesn't create the service which it doesn't. What you are referring to is completely different than what's being addressed in the question. He didn't compile what you linked to which is the Debian Apache source code which is acquired via `apt` for which he would indeed need to be root. He simply compiled the Apache source code which comes from here: https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi . Nothing that I've stated here is incorrect. What you have stated doesn't apply to what's being addressed here.