# Apache systemctl start httpd failed

Tags: apache-httpd

I got a Suse system with a apache2 web server. When i try to start apache i get a error, when i ask the status of apache2 i get the information that httpd not run. 
So now i try to start httpd

```
systemctl start httpd
```

but that not works, so i ask

```
systemctl status httpd
```

The result is:

```
httpd.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

How can i start httpd corecly ?

Comment: Please update your question with the complete output from `systemctl status httpd`. You should also review the system logs for specific messages that are relevant and include them as well.

Comment: And if you really want to blow 0xSheepdog's mind, you can put the output of `head -n 11 /usr/share/doc/packages/apache2/README-instances.txt` in the question too.  (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JdeBP has already commented in this direction, so I thought I'd flesh it out into an Answer.

[The SUSE README for Apache](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/Apache:Next/apache2/apache2-README-instances.txt?expand=1) says, in part:

> Dear System Administrator,
>
> SUSE Apache package comes with the possibility to run more instances
>   of Apache process on one system.
>
> As always,
>
> ```
> systemctl start apache2
> ```
>
> activates default instance of the server, which expects sysconfig
>   setting in /etc/sysconfig/apache2. If this file is not present, or
>   APACHE_HTTPD_CONF in there is not set, then it requires
>   /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.

... which seems to point out the error; you've attempted to start a unit named "httpd" when the unit is actually named "apache2". That also lines up with the evidence you saw, which said:

```
Reason: No such file or directory
```

... since there is no httpd.service file.

Comment: It's the same for Debian.  [Shh!  Don't tell people.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/481823/5132)  Also bear in mind what [the questioner will have seen resulting from that `head` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/514057/5132).  (-:

Comment: Sounds like it'll result in `No such file or directory` at this point, but hopefully this Answer will serve some other long-tail purpose.

Comment: When i ask for already running apache2 processes with ps -aux | grep apache2 i get no output. Also i uninstalled and installed again. But still the same error

Comment: okay, i fixed it. I uninstalled apache2 not totaly. after i . also delete /etc/sysconfig/apache2 and installed agan it works.