# SUSE: How to completely uninstall apache2 on machine

Tags: package-management, apache-httpd, suse

I got some bigger struggle on my SUSE machine with my `apache2` installation. So I want to uninstall/remove it completely to reinstall it.

When I use `sudo zypper rm apache2` some of my files are gone, but a lot of files in my `/etc/apache2` folder is still exist.

Should I delete them with `rm` too, or what is the cleanest way to delete `apache2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zypper` can't does **purge** (remove package and configuration) action like `apt/aptitude`. This fact isn't mentioned in any `man` page in SUSE system.

[Quote](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/510180-How-to-use-quot-purge-quot-on-openSUSE?p=2732016#post2732016):

> ...a program removing user's files is not a good idea.

So, you should to remove all your configuration files by hand with `rm` tool.

Comment: it was also necessary to delete the /etc/sysconfig/apache2 file manually. 
After the reinstall it works, thangs